# Android Facebook Login Cannot call LoginFragment with a null calling package

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, launchmode

I have added facebook login to my app.

First time I am able to login without any issue. But after login and then I logout. I am getting this error in the logcat.

```
E/LoginFragment: Cannot call LoginFragment with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
```

I searched google a bit. Some errors were resolved by setting launchmode to standard. I didn't specify any launchmode. But still I tried with

```
<activity
     android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
     android:launchMode="standard"/>
```

But got no success.

Here is my procedure to login.

1 Added FB dependency `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`

2 I initialize FB sdk in `Application` Class's `onCreate()` After `super.onCreate()`. `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);`

3 In my login activity created `CallbackManager` instance on the `onCreate()` of activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

4 I used a custom button to login. When I clicked on fb login button. I am using this code.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    //My Stuff Here
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,first_name,last_name,link,picture.type(large)");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    //Cancel Stuff
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    //Error Stuff
                }
            });        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((AppCompatActivity)context,
            Arrays.asList("public_profile, email"));
```

5 I registered for callbacks in onActivityResult()

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

6 And to logout I have used `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()`

7 But I try to login again with my custom button, the debug pointer goes to the line `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback()` but none of the methods (`onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)`, `onError()`, `onError(FacebookException exception)`) of the callback gets call. And I get a log saying `E/LoginFragment: Cannot call LoginFragment with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((AppCompatActivity)context,
            Arrays.asList("public_profile, email"));`

to
`LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            Arrays.asList("public_profile, email"));`

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me catch the issue. See my Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Facebook is not giving exact exception details here.

Answer of Sushobh Nadiger helped me get to the issue.

I wanted to isolate the facebook login code from my LoginActivity and return the JSONObject back to LoginActivity so I created a class for handling Social Login called SocialLogin.java and I registered the callback in SocialLogin.java via `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() { //More Stuff here  }` and called login for facebook `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions()` for more details see the full code in question.

**This was the actual issue. So I made these calls (registerCallback() and logInWithReadPermissions()) in my LoginActivity.java and it worked.**

However I as developer would think that a company like facebook should give us proper error rather than like this misleading error in my case so that our precious time could not be wasted.